# LIMIT in mysql subquery

Tags: php, mysql, json, limit

I have a problem with a MySQL statement.

I have this:

```
SELECT ad.*, 
  (SELECT img.image 
   FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_images AS img 
   WHERE img.aid = ad.aid LIMIT 1) AS img 
FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad 
WHERE fid = :fid 
ORDER BY cr_date DESC
```

Which works fine, but I need to get all images from `_images` table, so if I remove `LIMIT 1` I get

```
Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

The result from the SQL is outputted as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) MySQL aggregate function:

```
SELECT ad.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(img.image) FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_images AS img WHERE img.aid = ad.aid) AS img FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad WHERE fid = :fid ORDER BY cr_date DESC
```

Then [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) it in php or [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it in javascript later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that, when you say a select, mysql expects to get one entry at a time. Take a look at mysql JOIN statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
select ad.*, img.image 
from TABLE1 ad 
JOIN TABLE2 img on ad.aid = img.aid 
WHERE CONDITION 
ORDER BY cr_date DESC.
```